# Replace existing image, crop and convert uploads to .jpg

Tags: php, jpeg

I have a script for letting users upload profile pictures which saves it in the users folder as profile.(jpg/png/gif)

File upload is very new to me and I find it hard to implement other solutions from this site to my own work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['memberID'];
$target_dir = "../userContent/$user/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . "profile." . $imageFileType)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

how can I make sure the image is always saved as .jpg, cropped to 400x400 and replace existing profile picture if one exists?

Comment: you need to use `GD` http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: you also need to check if the upload actually occurred and SUCCEEDED. You're just assuming nothing will ever fail. There's an `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason, and should be checked FIRST. If it shows an error, then everything else in $_FILES for that particular file cannot be trusted/used. And your file extension checking is pointless. getimagesize already returns complete image type data, more reliably than testing the user-supplied filename.

Comment: @MarcB well, as I said, this is new to me, and the entire script is taken from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for your awesome attitude and help! You have really brightened my day and helped me solve my problem